# setContentOffset:animated: shows view background

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a UIScrollView with with different view controllers for each page inside it. When I use setContentOffset:animated: to scroll to a different page I can see a white line between the pages. This white line doesn't appear when I scroll by dragging the UIScrollView.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This white line is the background of the views added to the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Setting all of your backgrounds (as in all layers deep) to magenta is a good test, but you may find that doesn't help.  I have the same bug, but everything I have is black.  The white line is there scrolling some directions.